# JavaFX how to remove specific node by mouseSecondary button

Tags: java, javafx

I was confused by one of the exercises of my book. It requires me to create a circle on the position of my mouse arrow every time when I click Mouse Left button, and then delete this node if my mouse is just in this circle and I click the right button. Adding circle into pane is so easy, so I could finish it quickly but remove it quite hard, so I was trapped in this part, could someone add some codes in order to delete the circle?

```
package com.company;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AddOrDeletePoint extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        double radius = 5;
        pane.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            double X = e.getSceneX();
            double Y = e.getSceneY();
            Circle circle = new Circle(X, Y, radius);
            circle.setFill(Color.WHITE);
            circle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
                pane.getChildren().add(circle);
            } else if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
                pane.getChildren().remove(circle);//this is the remove part, but it does not work!
            }
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

[image]
So just like this, how to remove the circle from the pane if my mouse stays on that circle and then click the right button?

Comment: "Could someone add some codes" not really how this works, mate.

Comment: Sorry, my statement may be a little vague, my image is more clear.

Comment: Think about what you need to solve this. FIrst, you can't remove a circle you just created. You have to remove the one previously added. So you have to have them in some sort of collection. Then, when the user right-clicks, you have to go through them and find the circle to remove based on the x, y location of the mouse click. Work on each of those steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always create a circle. In case the secondary button is clicked, this circle was never added to the scene and nothing is removed from the child list of `pane`. You need to remove a existing circle.

Register the "Remove circle" listener to the circles you create:

```
pane.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
    if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
        double X = e.getX(); // remove pane's coordinate system here
        double Y = e.getY(); // remove pane's coordinate system here
        final Circle circle = new Circle(X, Y, radius);
        circle.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        circle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

        circle.setOnMouseClicked(evt -> {
            if (evt.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
                evt.consume();
                pane.getChildren().remove(circle);
            }
        });

        pane.getChildren().add(circle);
    }
});
```

Alternatively you could use the pick result:

```
pane.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
    if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
        double X = e.getX(); // remove pane's coordinate system here
        double Y = e.getY(); // remove pane's coordinate system here
        Circle circle = new Circle(X, Y, radius);
        circle.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        circle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

        pane.getChildren().add(circle);
    } else if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
        // check if cicle was clicked and remove it if this is the case
        Node picked = e.getPickResult().getIntersectedNode();
        if (picked instanceof Circle) {
            pane.getChildren().remove(picked);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It works! By the way, what is the function of `evt.consume();`?

Comment: @PanPan It prevents event delivery to nodes closer to the scene root. It's not really necessary in this case, but if you want to handle clicks with the secondary on the pane itself, it could help...